# MYSQL Not Exist not working

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

courseobjects table

```
id_objects |  type      |  id_type | completed | id_courses
41         |movie       |25        |0          |27 
42         |presentation|11        |0          |27
43         |movie       |26        |0          |27
```

## courseobjectsresults

```
id_courseresult | id_courseobject |id_user |result
92              |41               |62      |1
```

> I want to show rows of courseobjects table where id is not there in
>   courseobjectsresults (id_courseobject)

**I Tried:**

```
SELECT * FROM courseobjects WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM courseobjectsresults WHERE courseobjectsresults.id_courseobject <> '41')
```

Output I am getting is Null but it should show row from courseobject for id 42 and 43

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a bit wrong logically, and you're also just testing against id 41. Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM courseobjects
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM courseobjectsresults
    HERE courseobjectsresults.id_courseobject = courseobjects.id_objects
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute for not exists:

You can use (`where column IN`) and (`where column NOT IN`)